# Vmware на Linux : ошибка установки Vmware tools

Tags: linux, vmware, parrot

В общем основная система - `parrot os`, на ней установлена `Vmware tools` и на ней `Windows 7`. При попытке установить `VM tools` выходит ошибка

[image: Ошибка]

Кто знает, как установить VM tools на виртуальную винду с моего дистра?